# Python - len function not working as expected, and giving me the error "TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()"

Tags: python, function

While studying linked lists from - https://composingprograms.com/pages/23-sequences.html#linked-lists

```
empty ='empty'
four = [1, [2, [3, [4, 'empty']]]]
x = [1,2];

def is_link(s):
    """s is a linked list if it is empty or a (first, rest) pair."""
    return s == empty or (len(s) == 2 and is_link(s[1]))

print(is_link(four))
print(is_link(x))
```

The program recognizes four as a linked list, But when i plug in x it returns an error instead of returning "False".

If i change value of x to just [1] or [1,2,3] it returns as expected, but if i enter a normal list [1,2] with 2 values i run into this error. .Why is this?

Comment: It works for `[1]` and for `[1, 2, 3]` because the `len(s) == 2` condition fails and returns `False`. For `[1, 2]` - the length is 2, but the last element is an `int` which does not have a `len`

Comment: if you add `print(s)` right at the start of `is_link` it should be easy to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: @Mortz I think your answer is the correct logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the executions, on your condition `len(s) == 2` this only satisfies `[1, 2]` so it checks for the next one `is_link(s[1])` which raises an error because it's a check length of integer in next iteration.

```
In [24]: print(is_link([1]))
[1]
False

In [25]: print(is_link([1, 2, 3]))
[1, 2, 3]
False

In [26]: print(is_link([1, 2]))
[1, 2]
2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [26], in <module>
----> 1 print(is_link([1, 2]))

Input In [20], in is_link(s)
      2 print(s)
      3 """s is a linked list if it is empty or a (first, rest) pair."""
----> 4 return s == empty or (len(s) == 2 and is_link(s[1]))

Input In [20], in is_link(s)
      2 print(s)
      3 """s is a linked list if it is empty or a (first, rest) pair."""
----> 4 return s == empty or (len(s) == 2 and is_link(s[1]))

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Comment: Thanks, How do you get that type of tracebacks to  output if you dont mind sharing.

Comment: @zram I am using `ipython` to execute small code snippets. So, it's easier to understand the code and we can play around as well.

Comment: @zram you could get a more in depth traceback by recompiling python with debugger stuffs on

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this part:

```
is_link(s[1])
```

When you pass x[1] to is_link method s is 2 (has type int) thus it doesnt have len() method. You need to check whether the argument in method is_link is list like that

```
return type(s) == list and (s == empty or (len(s) == 2 and is_link(s[1])))
```

Comment: i did not downvote you but if what you say is true, lets say s =[1,2,3] should return error as well, but its returning  correct answer

Comment: this answer is wrong, the test for list-type needs to happen after the test for `empty`, ie. `return s == empty or (type(s)==list and len(s) == 2 and is_link(s[1]))`

Answer (score 1):

When you try `is_link([1,2])`, then, since the list is of length 2, it will try to evaluate `is_link(s[1])`. Which in this case is `is_link(2)`. Which then leads to `len(2)` which gives the error message, since 2 is not a list. `len` can only be applied on lists